# How do I add together every (x) numbers in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion, sum, radix

Define a function named series.  This function will accept two arguments, both integers, named base and span.  The function will compute the sum of the integers, starting at the value of base and down to 0 (zero) that are span apart.  In other words, if base is 19and span is 3, series will compute the sum of 19 +16 + 13 + 10 + 7 + 4 + 1.
The series function does not need to handle negative base and span values, and these should not be tested for.

This is the homework im struggling with, and what I have. I'm not sure how to iterate through a range of numbers and add them all together. Any and all help is appreciated.
Thanks!

```
def series ():
    base = int(238)
    span = int(9)
    range(base, int(0))
    sum((base) - (span), (span))
    if series() < 1:
        return 0
series()
```

Comment: This isn't a free homework service, please show what you've tried and ask specific questions on why it doesn't work.

Comment: What have you tried?  How would you "walk" somebody through the solution process if you had to tell them what to do?  You could use an iterative approach or a recursive approach, both of which would be O(base) work.  There's also an algebraic solution based on modulo arithmetic which relies on knowing that `sum(0..n) = n * (n + 1) / 2`, and which would take O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

Won't write the exact code but this will be the approach.  You can define a function with the following steps:

- If the base is less than 1 return 0
- Else return base + function(base - span, span)

Try yourself and if you are stuck, post the code that you tried.

Comment: list = range(100)
def series ():
base = 4
span = 6
if base < 1:
    return 0
else:
    return base + series(base - span, span)   I'm not sure how to iterate through a range of numbers doing the specific function of adding them together. I'm struggling

Comment: When talking about recursion, there is no concept of iteration. I suggest you read some basic codes like solving n factorial etc in python which will give you a better understanding of how recursion works. Basically, there is no use of ```range``` function when using recursion and make everything in function argument, not variable declaration, which is the baseline for recursion.